# Change IP settings using Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, network-programming

I need to provide a Python program  allowing the user to change dynamically the network parameters of his device (IP, mask, DNS & Gateway). For example, changing his IP from 192.168.1.10/24 to 192.168.1.15/24. I don't want to run my program as root - but I can give to my user some specifics rights (for instance add the user to a group which can modify the `/usr/network/interfaces` file).

What I found is the [pynetlinux](https://github.com/rlisagor/pynetlinux) library but it only provides IP and mask modifications and needs to be run as root (or maybe I missused it).

I could probably do it by parsing the `interfaces` file and running some bash/shell commands but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. I'm pretty sure some people already had my issue and did something great about it.

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04. I would need my programm to work also on Ubuntu 14.04, CentOS and RedHat

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to modify the network configuration files or you want to change the IP address and subnet mask on the fly, like `ifconfig` does?

Comment: I want for instance to be able to change the local IP address (for example from 192.168.1.10/24 to 192.168.1.11/24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to create a complete list of actions your program will have to execute. I found that in a similar setting, in response to user interaction we had to:

- modify config files (`interfaces`, `host`, `resolv.conf`, ...)
- echo to sysfs to change some settings
- start/stop certain network services
- switch firewall configuration (we did that via init script too)

We ended up creating a Bash script with a well-defined interface that a certain non-privileged user could call with `sudo` from any other program.

However our dialog-based frontend was written in Bash already so we did not spend much time in looking for existing libraries which surely is worth the effort in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, and yes if I don't find any library doing what I want, I'll end up writing my own bash or python script, but that would be unfortunate

Comment: You are definitely doing it in the right order :-) Good Luck.